# ar.js NFT Marker Generator Confidence rating

Tags: ar.js, nft

I was trying to generate NFT marker from:
https://carnaux.github.io/NFT-Marker-Creator/

[image]

I always got no star rating at the bottom no matter what images I tried.
Is the site broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not broken, I have tried two images, one give no star and one give four stars. I think it depends on how feature rich your image is so the AR program can easily recognize it from the environment. You can view the guidelines at:

https://github.com/Carnaux/NFT-Marker-Creator/wiki/Creating-good-markers